# How to draw a route between two locations on CloudMade

Tags: blackberry, java-me, routes, cloudmade

I'm trying to use CloudMade's route service.

I want to display a Route between two locations in my standalone application, but there isn't any tutorial in CloudMade's website that handle this.

How can I display the Route?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

for Blackberry/J2ME CloudMade only gives own tiles, libraries are from nutiteq.

Here are their examples including routing: http://www.nutiteq.com/lib-application-samples.